# Changing decoder output shape in convolutional autoencoder for training

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to train my dataset for the convolutional autoencoder model. I have patched 500,400x400x1 dataset. And my model is shown below.

```
input_img = Input(shape = (400, 400, 1))

def encoder(input_img):
#encoder
conv1 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img) 
conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2) 
conv3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2) 
conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv5)
conv6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool5)
conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
pool6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv6)
conv7 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool6) 
conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
pool7 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv7)
conv8 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool7)
conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
return conv8


def decoder(conv8):    
#decoder
conv9 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8) 
conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv9) 
conv12 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
conv12 = BatchNormalization()(conv12)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv12) 
conv13 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up2) 
conv13 = BatchNormalization()(conv13)
up3 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv13) 
conv14 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up3)
conv14 = BatchNormalization()(conv14)
up4 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv14) 
conv15 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up4)
conv15 = BatchNormalization()(conv15)
up5 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv15) 
conv16 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up5)
conv16 = BatchNormalization()(conv16)
up6 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv16) 
conv17 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6) 
conv17 = BatchNormalization()(conv17)
up7 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv17) 
conv18 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7) 
conv18 = BatchNormalization()(conv18)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv18)
return decoded
```

after the encoder process, the shape goes to (3,3,512). But when the decoder process is done, the shape goes up to (384,384,1). And because my input shape is (400,400,1), I can not train the model. Is there any upsampling way to change my decoder (384,384,1) layer to (400,400,1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the padding in intermediate Con2D layers to make up for the 16 pixels. See [this documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) for how to control padding on 2 dimensions.

You can also use explicit [padding layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#padding-layers).

Comment: First of all thank you for your interest. Can I change padding in Keras? besides when I  change padding to tuple or int  `'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'` error comes out.

Comment: Ah yes this is PyTorch documentation, add a keras tag to the question if the issue is keras specific, it can help you find the right answers. But for sure there must be an equivalent padding in keras/TensorFlow